# Android - Partial refresh listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I am working on an Android ListView that contains multiple item templates like my poor hand draw demonstrates below:

[image]

I know this is really poor so just let me explain a little more about the listview.

As you can see, the whole activity contains **one single ListView**, in which the 0 position of the ListView is the `Header` part. Below the header at position 1 of the list I have a item that contains two tabs `b1` and `b2`. From position 3, the list item will display depending on the selection of the tab.

For example, if user select `b1` tab, the items showing from position 3 should use template `card 1` as shown in my hand draw. If then user select `b2`, the rest of the listview should refresh and update to use `card 2` template.

If I still did not make it clear, please refer to the Vine Android app's profile page. Where if you choose `POST` you will see your list of posts show up, and if you choose `LIKES` you will see all your liked posts.

So I was wondering if there's a way to **force the ListView to refresh from the 3rd position** to adapt the correct data?

Comment: no, there is no such option

Comment: I doubt this is a good idea in the first place. What about scrolling? Do you want your header to disappear? (you cannot rely on screen size in android). But still, if you really want to go this way: what's wrong with also refreshing the header? I doubt you'll even notice.

Comment: @Heuster I would also like to know if there's other options to do the same thing like Vine Android App profile page does?

Comment: What I would do: make one layout containing the header and a tab view (see [the android designer pages](https://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html)). Make a fragment per tab and just use a simple listview layout for those. Adding multiple types of items to the same list is a pain, so I wouldn't, unless really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep too list for your data item:

1: To store original data state

2: To store display data

Now you pass 2nd to the adapter and if B1 is selected just change the data inside 2nd list and notify adapter.

Now if B2 is click get the data from 1st list change it and set to 2nd list and notify adapter.

Adapter refreshes for the whole list so just change the items that you want to refresh.